# Libgdx NullPointerException on everything after update, even default code

Tags: java, android, gradle, opengl-es, libgdx

I updated my Android Studio, Gradle, Libgdx and everything. Now when I try to run the DesktopLauncher I get a NullPointerException

```
com.psillicoder.tdg.desktop.DesktopLauncher
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.createDisplayPixelFormat(LwjglGraphics.java:322)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setupDisplay(LwjglGraphics.java:216)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:142)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
```

The code was working perfectly fine before the updates. I tried to rebuild gradle as well and received an error code:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\hp\AndroidStudioProjects\TechnoBrick\build.gradle' line: 47

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'TechnoBrick'.
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4 mins 10.457 secs
```

I'm at a loss as to what to do.

I know my version of OpenGL is supported, as like I said, the code was working before the updates. I tried creating a new project and running that and got the same error message.

I have tried updating to java 1.8 as well as changing the buildtools version..Still getting the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 when rendering in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937875/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0-when-rendering-in-android-studio)

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with that question. I know what a NullPointerException is. I shouldn't be getting one on default code or any code that I run the desktoplauncher with.

Comment: Duplicate of a generic NPE question?  Are you kidding?  This is not even close to that.