# Gradle wrapper version issues

Tags: java, android, gradle, version

My task is to build an `apk` file using gradle wrapper via command line. I have a project in Android Studio `2.2.3`, it has a line in build.gradle file `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'`, which should mean, that it is using gradle version 2.2.3. But when I call gradlew command from the project folder, there is always the same error: `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`

I've used `gradlew -v` to recognize my gradle version, it is now `2.2.1`. Though when I manually change gradle version in build.gradle file from `2.2.3` to `2.2.1` I still get the same error.

I checked the folder containing gradle on my computer. It has gradle version `2.14.1`.

I tried:

- changing JDK path from 1.7 to 1.8 (JAVA_HOME variable)
- manually changing JDK location at Project Structure -> SDK Location settings
- in gradle settings: switching between using default gradle wrapper and local gradle distribution.

Interesting thing is that when I change gradle version in build.gradle to `1.5.0` the version error disappears, but I can no longer make any builds(it becomes unable to merge several `jar` files into one `apk` file)

What is this version hell and how do I get rid of this error?

**EDIT #1:**

My */gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties* content is:

```
#Fri Oct 21 12:53:56 EEST 2016
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

**EDIT #2:**

I figured out that gradle versions are the same. So what JDK and JRE version should I use and how do I update them? Simply downloading into Java folder and changing JDK location in Project Structure didn't help.
[image]

**EDIT #3:**

My build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My project-level build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0"
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

I needed to update targetSdkVersion and all dependencies to version 25 and set JAVA_HOME to jdk 1.8. Thanks, Abhishek Aryan

Comment: What ist the content of your <your-project>/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi/11432195#11432195

Comment: @joe updated my question.

Comment: Have you read this answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937875/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0-when-rendering-in-android-studio

Comment: @joe yes, first of all I've made all updates in Android Studio, including downloading the latest SDK tools. It made no difference.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51392464/8034839

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle version is different from Android Plugin for Gradle version.

This is Android Plugin for Gradle with version

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
```

And gradle with version

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

Comment: In my case I am using gradle version 2.14.1, Android build tool version  2.2.0 with JDK 1.8

Comment: need your app build.gradle file, you updated your root build file

Comment: added project-level build.gradle file

Comment: you need to check which buildToolsVersion is supported by androidgradlebuildtool version 2.2.3. As I am using 2.2.0 which depends on buildToolsVersion 23.0.2 or higher and Gradle 2.14.1 or higher