# I can not update my gradle plugin Android Studio in Ubuntu 14.0.4

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-2.2

I have been trying to update my gradle plugin and is failing at it. My current gradle plugin is 2.1.2 and i want to update it to 2.2.0. I updated android studio and gradle plugin is still same. I have download gradle 3.3 manually and set gradle plugin source to this. On android official website 3.3 supports 2.3.0 but android studio gives me error on both 2.3.0 and 2.2.0 plugin versions:

```
Error:Cause: com/android/build/gradle/internal/ide/DefaultAndroidProject : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

I have replaced gradle-wrapper.properties with this string

```
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

**EDIT 1:**
This question is different from previous question posted here `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937875/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0-when-rendering-in-android-studio`
as this question is not asking help in unsupported major.minor problem but rather is talking about how can i update my plugin.

**Edit 2:**

I solved my problem by checking for updates in android studio which redirected me to download latest version of android studio. I downloaded and installed latest version of android studio which came with gradle plugin 2.3 and it is working fine now. You can check for updates by following this navigation.

Goto `Help->Check for Updates`

**EDIT 3:**
If while updating android studio gives error of connection timed out, then please change your Internet connection and try again. I faced this problem and resolved it by changing my internet connection.

Comment: The problem is, that your JVM is too old. It will work with Java 8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 when rendering in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937875/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0-when-rendering-in-android-studio)

Comment: i manually downloaded new android studio and installed it, it is working now.