# gradlew/Android Studio - Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradlew, build-error

I am running:

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

from my project folder and getting the error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

I have the following build.gradle:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and I have:

[image]

Comment: on the cli use -D $myJava8SDK  with your gradlew exec   to run java 8 and get rid of the error

Comment: I believe that version of Gradle needs Java 8.  If you want to stay with Java 7, change to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'`   Also note that you'll need to use buildToolsVersion lower than 24 in your app level  build.gradle, for example: `buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"`  The other option is to get fully set up with Java 8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 when rendering in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937875/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0-when-rendering-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the java in /usr/bin/java from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

and it builds now.